# Simple Linear Regression Machine Learning Course

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Your friend in the U.S. gives you a simple regression fit for predicting house prices from square feet. The estimated intercept is -44850 and the estimated slope is 280.76. You believe that your housing market behaves very similarly, but houses are measured in square meters. To make predictions for inputs in square meters, what intercept must you use? Hint: there are 0.092903 square meters in 1 square foot. You do not need to round your answer.

Comment: Intercept doesn't change, slope does.

Comment: So, the answer will be the same as the problem? for the intercept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear regressions do not depend on units. The intercept is $-\$44,850$, and the slope $\$280.76/\text{ft}^{2}$ converts to:
$$\$280.76/\text{ft}^{2} = \frac{\text{ft}^{2}}{.092903\text{m}^{2}} \cdot \$280.76/\text{ft}^{2} = \$3022.08/\text{m}^{2}$$
(You can similarly convert dollars into whatever currency you like.)